# Platform String for iPad Pro

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, ipad

I know the platform strings for the new iPhone 6s & 6s Plus:

- iPhone8,1: iPhone 6s Plus
- iPhone8,2: iPhone 6s

But what is the platform string for the new iPad Pro?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The platform string for *iPad Pro* is: *iPad6,8*

Also, here is the snippet with all platform strings since the beginning of time:

```
// Gets a string with the device model
size_t size;
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
char *machine = malloc(size);
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
free(machine);

if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 2G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"])    return @"iPhone 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"iPhone 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])    return @"iPhone 6 Plus";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])    return @"iPhone 6";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,1"])    return @"iPhone 6s";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,2"])    return @"iPhone 6s Plus";

if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (1 Gen)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (2 Gen)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (3 Gen)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (4 Gen)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (5 Gen)";

if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,2"])      return @"iPad 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])      return @"iPad Air (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])      return @"iPad Air (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])      return @"iPad Mini 2 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])      return @"iPad Mini 2 (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,6"])      return @"iPad Mini 2";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,7"])      return @"iPad Mini 3";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,8"])      return @"iPad Mini 3";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,9"])      return @"iPad Mini 3";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,1"])      return @"iPad Mini 4 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,2"])      return @"iPad Mini 4 (LTE); 
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,3"])      return @"iPad Air 2";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,4"])      return @"iPad Air 2";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad6,8"])      return @"iPad Pro";

if ([platform isEqualToString:@"AppleTV2,1"])   return @"Apple TV 2G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"AppleTV3,1"])   return @"Apple TV 3";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"AppleTV3,2"])   return @"Apple TV 3 (2013)";

if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";
```

Comment: I believe this is missing `AppleTV5,3`, which is the new 4th generation Apple TV.

Comment: `iPad6,7` - iPad Pro Wifi Only.. And `iPad 6,8` is Cellular version

Comment: Any idea for the 9.7 inch new iPad pro?

Answer (score 4):

To obtain an updated list of device models, check out this site: http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models